# Making joins using rowid in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I was wondering if the following code is a good practice

```
CURSOR c_price_hist_parent IS 
  select tran_type, reason, event,
         unit_cost, unit_retail, selling_unit_retail,
         selling_uom, multi_units, multi_unit_retail,
         multi_selling_uom 
    from price_hist
   where rowid = ( SELECT row_id 
                     from ( SELECT rowid row_id
                              FROM price_hist 
                             WHERE item = l_item_parent
                               and tran_type in (4,8)
                               and loc = l_location
                               and ACTION_DATE <= l_create_date
                             order by action_date desc 
                           )
                    where rownum = 1 
                  );
```

If we delete a row and then insert the same row all the columns remain same but the `rowid` doesn't, so in this case it will not match. Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? There are more than a few reasons why `rowid` may change - reinsertion of a row is only one of them. What exactly is your goal? `I was wondering if the following code is a good practice` a good practice for what?

Comment: Using rowid to do joins is not a good practice. Put the table structures, please.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in using rowid as long as you dont save it for later. As lookup using the rowid is very effecient it is possible to think up scenarioes where it makes sense to use it on the fly. Wether it is good practice in this case I cant say.

Comment: @Jens _"There is nothing wrong in using rowid as long as you dont save it for later."_ can't `rowid` being invalidated by concurrent transactions?

Comment: ROWIDs can change, and I've not seen this approach before. Do you not have natural keys you can use to uniquely identify your records?

Comment: @Sylvain - yes concurrent transactions can invalidate rowid. But I believe Oracle's read consistency will ensure that you get a consistent dataset throughout the lifetime of a single query.

Comment: It seems that Asfakul wants to have only the latest row by ACTION_DATE. You can obtain that by using the inner WHERE directly with your main SELECT - without the sub-select that is. All you need to do then is to fetch only the first row from the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, using rownum can be tricky, because inserts or deletes can happen at the same time which could change rownums.
If I understand your query correctly, you are simply trying to get the record with the latest action_date. Why not do the following:

```
CURSOR c_price_hist_parent IS 
  select sub.tran_type, sub.reason, sub.event,
         sub.unit_cost, sub.unit_retail, sub.selling_unit_retail,
         sub.selling_uom, sub.multi_units, sub.multi_unit_retail,
         sub.multi_selling_uom 
    from (
     select *
       from price_hist
      where item = l_item_parent
        and tran_type in (4,8)
        and loc = l_location
        and ACTION_DATE <= l_create_date
      order by action_date desc
    ) sub
  where rownum = 1
);
```